# How to only get the tuples I want from a list of tuples? [Haskell]

Tags: haskell, tuples, list-comprehension

I'm trying to set up a list of tuples from a list of Integers in this form:
(a,b) a <- [1..4] and b <- xs. But I keep getting all the different combinations of the statement.

```
okTup :: [Int] -> [(Int,Int)]
okTup xs = [(i,j) | i <- [1..4], j <- xs]
```

Input: okTup **[3,1,4,2]**

What I get is this:
[(1,3),(1,1),(1,4),(1,2),(2,3),(2,1),(2,4),(2,2),(3,3),(3,1),(3,4),(3,2),(4,3),(4,1),(4,4),(4,2)]

But I only want this:
[(1,**3**),(2,**1**),(3,**4**),(4,**2**)]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That’s [`zip`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zip):

```
okTup xs = zip [1..] xs
```

If you prefer to do this with a list comprehension, or you want to extend an existing comprehension, you can use the `ParallelListComp` extension, which allows you to write:

```
okTup xs = [(i, j) | i <- [1..] | j <- xs]
```

(Note the vertical bar `|` instead of a comma `,`.)

Of course, this essentially just uses `zip` under the hood.